# Android application with maps not working, while showing no errors,

Tags: android, android-activity, android-maps

I have done all of the Google play services and have imported them all

```
public class Check extends Activity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("KIEL")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15:
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in with animation:
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Application not working", with **no details**, doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Google Maps API key.
You should register and get key and put it in your application in order 
to be able to use their Api.
See this link  :
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: Yes, I have registered and got the key and all of the packages, yet it doesn't seem to work.